# how can I untrack files in a branch that is not my current branch

Tags: git

I have 2 git branches 'Master' and 'Work'.

I had been working on my 'Work' Branch for a while. In work I untracked all my *.png files and added *.png to my gitignore.

The master branch is still tracking *.png.

Now I can't checkout my master branch because git is complaining that my untracked files would be over written by checkout.

I can't checkout my master branch and merge my work branch into it.

How can I tell my master branch to stop tracking *.png.

I know you usually use rm -r --cached to remove files but I only know how to do that from the current branch.

Comment: If you merge your work to master, master should stop tracking those files as well.

Comment: as in git merge master/work  ?

Comment: `git checkout master && git merge work`. Use `git checkout -f master` to overwrite any existing/conflicting changes. Use with care, better make a backup first (or `stash` your changes). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to move the files aside, checkout master and either repeat the changes there are better cherry-pick the removes/gitignore-additions into master, and then checkout your branch again and move the files back.  That's the safest way (especially if you have changes to the PNGs).

Answer (score 0):

Use .git/info/exclude If you wish the exclude patterns based on repositories , you may instead put them in a file in that specific repository named .git/info/exclude or core.excludesfile